# UITapGestureRecognizer cause view not deallocate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I ran into a weird bug :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap)];
    TestView *testView = [[TestView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [testView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    [self.view addSubview:testView];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"testView removeFromSuperview");
        [testView removeFromSuperview];
    });

}


-(void)tap{
    NSLog(@"test");
}
```

TestView is a subclass of UIView that prints log when `-(void)dealloc` is called.
If I do nothing and wait till the testView removes from its superview,the console logs :

```
2016-08-25 15:08:30.176 TapTest[12786:238984] testView removeFromSuperview
2016-08-25 15:08:30.176 TapTest[12786:238984] test view dealloc
```

However , if i tap on the view that actually triggers the tap action,the console only logs :

```
2016-08-25 15:09:43.605 TapTest[12802:240217] test
2016-08-25 15:09:45.306 TapTest[12802:240217] testView removeFromSuperview
```

I've done quite some research , but still have no idea of what's going on.

I am using Xcode 7.3(7D175) and iOS9.

EDIT: A friend of mine says this has something to do with runloop and autorealease pool , and after testView is removed from superview , i tap on the view again to trigger the next runloop , and the text view is deallocated.

Comment: If your project is using ARC, which I assume it is, dealloc method should not be called anyway.

Comment: @RoyK You're wrong. ARC or no ARC, dealloc is always called when an object is deallocated.

Comment: Is there any custom code in your `TestView` class ?

Comment: @deadbeef no , only override dealloc to print logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to an implementation detail of the touch management system.
As you've mentioned in your edit, if you touch the view once more after your `TestView` has been removed, you will notice that it gets deallocated at this point.

If you set a breakpoint in `dealloc`, you will see that it gets deallocated when a `UITouch` gets deallocated.

At this point you can only guess what is happening, but most probable thing is that iOS keeps around the last touch that happened with a `UITouch` object. An a `UITouch` keeps a reference to the view in which the touch happened (see the `view` property of `UITouch`). In this case this is your `TestView` and this is why it doesn't get deallocated immediately.

Comment: Thanks ! iOS keeps the last UITouch object explains why the runloop and autorelease is "not working"  !

Answer (score 0):

I have figured something.

I added some tricks for catching retain count on arc.

`NSLog(@"testView removeFromSuperview -> %d", (int)[testView performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"retainCount")]);`

none tap:

> testView removeFromSuperview -> 3

with tap:

> testView removeFromSuperview -> 4

something has grabbed testview in tap gesture with click tap event once or more. I guess this happening by relative with some logic on main run loop event.

so funny question. thank you. I will digging more.

Comment: just more tap after removed, finally run deallocation. with no tap doing deallocation in autorelease pool. but with tap doing deallocation with UIApplicationHandleEventQueue.

Comment: >  [testView performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"release")]; forcing release after tapping immediately occur delloc.

Comment: I don't think calling release directly is a good idea .. since it's obvious that some other object is managing the view's life cycle , i found this in Apple's Documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITouch/view) , an UITouch object strongly holds the view that the touches are being delivered . And like @deadbeef said , it seems that iOS keeps the last UITouch object in memory ,therefore the view isn't released immediately.

Comment: You can add a breakpoint inside TestView's dealloc method , without touch , you can see dealloc is called when autoreleasepool is performing pop , and with a touch ,  dealloc is called when an UITouch object is destructing.

Comment: @Gocy015 I agreed with it. It's bad idea. just for testing. 